# PDFBox Library to read Invisible PDFSignature from Signed PDF..Signer name is not shown

Tags: java, pdfbox

For a signed PDF document, with invisible signature, I am using PDFBox library to extract signer information, but it's coming as null. Same code works fine for visible signature. Can someone help on this if we need to make?

```
//Load PDF Document
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(doc);

    //Iterate each Signature
    for (PDSignature pdSignature : document.getSignatureDictionaries()) {
        if (pdSignature != null) {
            HashMap values = new HashMap();
            String subFilter = pdSignature.getSubFilter();
            if (subFilter != null) {
                LOG.debug("---------Siganature Details---------- ");
                LOG.debug("Signer Name : " + pdSignature.getName());
                values.put(SignerName, pdSignature.getName());
```

Comment: `pdSignature.getName()` is optional.

Comment: Use the ShowSignature.java example for more information about the certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pdSignature.getName()` returns the value of the **Name** entry of the signature dictionary. But this entry is optional:

> **Name** text string *(Optional)* The name of the person or authority signing the document.
> This value should be used only when it is not possible to extract the name from the signature.

Generally you'll have to analyze the signer certificate in the embedded signature container to get the common name of the signer.

As @Tilman pointed out in a comment, the pdfbox example [ShowSignature](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/ShowSignature.java) shows quite a number of means to retrieve data from a CMS signature container.

#### On Your Comment

In a comment you write

> Only the complete principal string can be extracted which contains the complete string using the below code "certFromSignedData.getSubjectX500Principal().toString()" [...] Any direct way of querying CN name alone?

Indeed you only get the complete subject distinguished name if you apply `toString()` to the `X500Principal` returned by `certFromSignedData.getSubjectX500Principal()`. But if you create a `sun.security.x509.X500Name` for it, you can easily retrieve the common name:

```java
X500Principal principal = certFromSignedData.getSubjectX500Principal();
sun.security.x509.X500Name name = sun.security.x509.X500Name.asX500Name(principal);
System.out.printf("Whole DN: %s\n", name);
System.out.printf("CN: %s\n", name.getCommonName());
```

If you don't want to use `sun.security.x509` classes, you can similarly use BouncyCastle classes, starting from the matching BouncyCastle `X509CertificateHolder`:

```java
org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name name = certificateHolder.getSubject();
System.out.printf("Whole DN: %s\n", name);
RDN[] cns = name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN);
System.out.printf("CN: %s\n", cns.length > 0 ? cns[0].getFirst().getValue() : null);
```

> however it's in different format for invisible and visible signature. For visible signature: SERIALNUMBER=xxxx, DNQ=xxx, EMAILADDRESS=xx, SURNAME=xx, GIVENNAME=xx, C=xx, CN=xx and for invisible signature "CN="xx" + EMAILADDRESS=xx, OU=xx, O="xx", L=xx, ST=xx, C=xx".

Which attributes are used in the subject DN and whether RDNs with multiple attribute/value pairs are used, depends on the signer certificate alone, it does not have anything to do with visible and invisible signature. If you have distinct specific patterns for invisible and visible signatures, then your test PDF pool is biased.

Comment: Thanks Mkl and Tilman..As suggested, signature container from certificate has a object subject and it has a field CN, it looks like having signer name..I am testing more cases.  I am new to Digital Signature and this is my first question in stack over flow :-) Thanks a lot..

Comment: *"I am new to Digital Signature"* - In that case you may also be interested in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) with some backgrounds on PDF signing. *"this is my first question in stack over flow"* - ok; in that case, if you feel an answer appropriately solved the issue, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking the check mark at its upper left.

Comment: Only the complete principal string can be extracted which contains the complete string using the below code "certFromSignedData.getSubjectX500Principal().toString()"  however it's in different format for invisible and visible signature.  For visible signature: SERIALNUMBER=xxxx, DNQ=xxx, EMAILADDRESS=xx, SURNAME=xx, GIVENNAME=xx, C=xx, CN=xx  and for invisible signature "CN="xx" + EMAILADDRESS=xx, OU=xx, O="xx", L=xx, ST=xx, C=xx".   Any direct way of querying CN name alone?